# Java sound visualizer

Tags: java, audio, audio-processing, real-time-java

i'm trying to make a java sound visualizer, but I have absolutely no idea on how to get the bytes from the audio extracted, immediately after they are procressed in real-time. I could synchronize the program with an wav file, but that is not what I want to do, I want to generate the sound with the program, then play it, without saving it anywhere.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What platform? Desktop Java? Web applet? Android?

Comment: Windows, desktop java and/or applet, not android

Comment: Your question leaves me a bit confused: Are you trying to visualize audio that's being played from, e.g., a WAV or MP3 file ("how to get the bytes from the audio extracted"), or do you want to play and visualize programmatically generated data ("I want to generate the sound with the program")?

Comment: I want to play and visualize the programatically generated data

Answer (score 7):

This article can help you understand the structure of sound files: [Build an Audio Waveform Display](https://web.archive.org/web/20090221151851/http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Audio/Build-an-Audio-Waveform-Display/)

Comment: Your link died, any chance you have something now? It would be good if you could improve your answer

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20090221151851/http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Audio/Build-an-Audio-Waveform-Display/