# Creating a flat sound wave (waveform) image from audio file

Tags: audio, mp3, visualization, waveform

I've been searching quite a lot but couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to generate a simplified or flat sound wave image from a very short audio file (1 sec mp3 in my case)?

Simplified may be the wrong term for it, but what I mean by that is I want this kind of output:

[image]

And not this:

[image]

I know I can zoom in a lot and search for a visually nice part of the wave but I'm more interested in generating a wave image that looks like a pulse image and **represents** the whole audio, in some way.

It may be in any way you can think of.. **Precision is not important here!**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I needed it

Answer (score 1):

Well first you need a way to visualize Sound, try this.

[Java sound visualizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723530/java-sound-visualizer)

You would than instead of visualizing every single sample(sound frame), calculate the avarage of multiple samples and use that to render your Waveform.

The simpler you want it the more samples should you use for your avarage.