# Is there a way to monitor live system volume in Java?

Tags: java, windows, audio, system-monitoring

I am currently trying to figure out how to make it so that Java actively monitors and sets system sound volume. The end goal of the software is to look for spikes in volume (ex. movies), and decrease the volume at those spikes as to not disturb the listener. Any ideas for monitoring and controlling sound? I am using Windows 10 if that helps. I am looking for something that monitors live system audio, not audio from a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java sound visualizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723530/java-sound-visualizer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java algorithm for normalizing audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469361/java-algorithm-for-normalizing-audio)

Comment: Your approach would at best be a reactive solution, which means when something loud happens, it would be too loud for a short period before your app corrected. If your goal is to not blast the users, you need a proactive filter in the audio rendering path. Why not just enable the built-in loudness equalization? https://www.ghacks.net/2014/04/02/enable-sound-loudness-equalization-windows/

Comment: There is no Java API to set the system sound volume. All the Java sound APIs only change the sounds from the current JVM.